# How to create custom shape button with fill color options in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

When user click the favorite button the button filled with color. The button shape will be heart shape. Please suggest me your valuable suggestion to achieve this. I have attached the screenshot of the button, please refer,

[image]

Comment: are you using any model to displaying the favorites. Are you using in listview

Comment: @Prasanth, Yes i have binding the isFavorite property to the button.

Comment: You need to show on listView?

Comment: @Prasanth, No, i am not using listview to show the favorite button.

Comment: then its should be easy. I updated in answer inside the button action in your viewmodel class, based on the property isFavorite selection changed the image

Comment: @Prasanth, Thanks for sharing your knowledge. But is there any other way to set the image as path image like in wpf.

Comment: I didn't have experince in wpf, but its okey can you post your code what you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, You need two images favorite filled and unfilled. At first the 'isFavorite' property should false I think. In your ViewModel inside button action trigger

```
private void ButtonActionForFavouriteTriggered(object seletecedButtonItem)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("favourite button clickked");
        var selectedList = (Result)seletecedButtonItem;

        if (selectedList.isFavorite == "Fav.png")
        {
            // update api or local DB whatever on here
            selectedList.isUserFavorite = false;
            selectedList.isFavorite = "unFav.png"; // this will update in UI - changes from favorite image into unfavorite image
        }
        else
        {
            // update api or local DB whatever on here
            selectedList.isUserFavorite = true;
            selectedList.favourite = "Fav.png"; // this will update in UI
        }
    }
```

Here 'Result' is my model and inside your model you can use 'INotifyPropertyChanged' interface like this.

```
 public class Result: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isUserFavorite { get; set; }

    //Note: If you want to change any thing without reload cells, use this type and inherit 'INotifyPropertyChanged'
    // Example: Favourite and UnFavourite button action, tapping any event change any text from cell

    public string abbr {
        get { return _abbr; } 
        set { _abbr = value;  OnPropertyChanged("abbr"); }
    }
    public string area { get; set; }
    public string largest_city { get; set; }
    public string capital { get; set; }
    public string isFavourite 
    { 
        get { return _fav; }
        set { 
               _fav = value; OnPropertyChanged("isFavourite");
            }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string _fav;
    public string _abbr;


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
    }
}
```

and in xaml, inside the listview or some other;

```
 <Button Grid.Column="3" x:Name="buttonFavourite" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="{Binding isFavourite}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyCollectionPage}, Path=BindingContext.FavouriteButtonAction}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
```